# How to solve java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61 and Entity was compiled with an unsuppported JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I am trying to develop an app with a database and i got lots of error like
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61** and **[EL Severe]: metadata: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.982--ServerSession(422250493)--The database.model.StageEntity class was compiled with an unsupported JDK. Report this error to the EclipseLink open source project.**
for every entity created through mapping. This is a Maven project so i didn't find any infos about it, only gradle. I work on java 17(17.0.2) and i am not familliar with intellij or Java in general, hopefully i will have someone who might find an answer for my problem. This is my persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<persistence-unit name="PersistenceMIP">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>database.model.StageEntity</class>
    <class>database.model.StageTeamEntity</class>
    <class>database.model.TeamEntity</class>
    <class>database.model.UserEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MIP"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and this is my pom.xml file

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
>      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>
> <groupId>org.example</groupId>
> <artifactId>MIP1</artifactId>
> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
>
> <properties>
>     <maven.compiler.source>17.0.2</maven.compiler.source>
>     <maven.compiler.target>17.0.2</maven.compiler.target>
> </properties> <dependencies>
>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
>     <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
>     <version>17.0.1</version>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
>     <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
>     <version>17.0.1</version>
> </dependency>
>
>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
>     <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
>     <version>2.7.7</version>
> </dependency>
>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
>     <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
>     <version>2.2.1</version>
> </dependency>
>
>
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
>     <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
>     <version>42.2.2</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

and here it's a lith with all my warning and errors

```
  enter code here[EL Info]: transaction: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.954--ServerSession(422250493)--property eclipselink.jdbc.user is deprecated, property javax.persistence.jdbc.user should be used instead.
[EL Info]: transaction: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.959--ServerSession(422250493)--property eclipselink.jdbc.driver is deprecated, property javax.persistence.jdbc.driver should be used instead.
[EL Info]: transaction: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.96--ServerSession(422250493)--property eclipselink.jdbc.url is deprecated, property javax.persistence.jdbc.url should be used instead.
[EL Info]: transaction: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.96--ServerSession(422250493)--property eclipselink.jdbc.password is deprecated, property javax.persistence.jdbc.password should be used instead.
[EL Severe]: metadata: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.982--ServerSession(422250493)--The database.model.StageEntity class was compiled with an unsupported JDK. Report this error to the EclipseLink open source project.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
[EL Severe]: metadata: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.984--ServerSession(422250493)--The database.model.StageEntity class was compiled with an unsupported JDK. Report this error to the EclipseLink open source project.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out of bounds for length 0
[EL Severe]: metadata: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.984--ServerSession(422250493)--The database.model.StageTeamEntity class was compiled with an unsupported JDK. Report this error to the EclipseLink open source project.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
[EL Severe]: metadata: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.985--ServerSession(422250493)--The database.model.StageTeamEntity class was compiled with an unsupported JDK. Report this error to the EclipseLink open source project.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out of bounds for length 0
[EL Severe]: metadata: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.985--ServerSession(422250493)--The database.model.TeamEntity class was compiled with an unsupported JDK. Report this error to the EclipseLink open source project.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
[EL Severe]: metadata: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.985--ServerSession(422250493)--The database.model.TeamEntity class was compiled with an unsupported JDK. Report this error to the EclipseLink open source project.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out of bounds for length 0
[EL Severe]: metadata: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.985--ServerSession(422250493)--The database.model.UserEntity class was compiled with an unsupported JDK. Report this error to the EclipseLink open source project.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
[EL Severe]: metadata: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.986--ServerSession(422250493)--The database.model.UserEntity class was compiled with an unsupported JDK. Report this error to the EclipseLink open source project.
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 8 out of bounds for length 0
[EL Info]: transaction: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.993--ServerSession(422250493)--property eclipselink.jdbc.user is deprecated, property javax.persistence.jdbc.user should be used instead.
[EL Info]: transaction: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.994--ServerSession(422250493)--property eclipselink.jdbc.driver is deprecated, property javax.persistence.jdbc.driver should be used instead.
[EL Info]: transaction: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.994--ServerSession(422250493)--property eclipselink.jdbc.url is deprecated, property javax.persistence.jdbc.url should be used instead.
[EL Info]: transaction: 2022-01-26 17:43:20.994--ServerSession(422250493)--property eclipselink.jdbc.password is deprecated, property javax.persistence.jdbc.password should be used instead.
[EL Info]: 2022-01-26 17:43:21.094--ServerSession(422250493)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d
[EL Warning]: metamodel: 2022-01-26 17:43:21.352--The collection of metamodel types is empty. Model classes may not have been found during entity search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units.  Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using either <class> elements or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element
Transaction error: Object: database.model.UserEntity@248df8 is not a known Entity type.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: errors like this mean you are trying to execute the code on an older jre compared to the jdk you used to compile your code.

Comment: The single version i run it on was java 17

Comment: so if i hava java 8 installed on my computer it may compile it with jre 8?

Comment: i unninstalled that version and i tried to build it again, still same errors

Comment: you need java 17. chances are, you're using some library that is compiled with java 17, lower won't do

Comment: so i should install java 17 ? but isn't it already present in the ide?

Comment: ehm? are you asking us what JDK you have installed? You can check, and maybe it does, but it's possible to switch jdk versions in your ide.

Comment: So right now i have openjdk 17.0.2 and the thing it says is that this version is not supported, right? Would't that mean i should downgrade?

Comment: no. what your error message is saying is that you are not compiling using java 17, yet that one source you use somewhere is compiled with java 17, so you need to use at least java 17

Comment: I understood but i still can 't solve it, everywhere i look there is the same java version so it looks good but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you mentioned may also be due to using a library which does some kind of code inspection/generation and is not yet ready to work with this very young class file version. Probably eclipselink is the problem here. Try to upgrade to the latest version and if that does not help go back to Java 16 and totally clean and rebuild your project.

See for example this note: [UPDATE ECLIPSELINK TO SUPPORT ASM 9.1 FOR JAVA 17](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PH37916)

Comment: Thank you, this was my problem